# @Version in hibernate, when running in cluster env does not work...(Optimistic Lock)

Tags: hibernate, concurrency, version, cluster-computing, optimistic-locking

I have an Entity  which uses @version on one of its fields, i want to achieve that if two transactions modify this entity in the same time, one will fail(and get Optimistic Lock Exception) and the other will succeed.

when i run this test on a single JVM this works fine, but when i run in a cluster env, the two transactions succeed AND NO Optimistic Lock is thrown.

```
public class DeploymentLock  {

    @Column(name = "DEPLOYMENT_COUNTER")
    private Long deploymentCounter;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_VERSION")
    private Long version;
    ...
}
```

am i missing something? do i need to use "@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)" under the @Version?

Im using Spring and hibrnate in my app by the way...
any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two instances of `DeploymentLock` inside of two *different* hibernate sessions (usually in two different JVMs or on two different hosts) each with the same `version` value, then the 2nd of the updates that you call should throw `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException`.

Basically hibernate is doing something like:

```
UPDATE DeploymentLock SET deploymentCounter = ..., version = 2 WHERE version = 1
```

Then if the update did not change the row the exception is thrown.

Are you sure that the two different JVMs (or two sessions) have the same instance with the same `version` value?  Could it be that there is a `refresh()` somewhere you don't expect or maybe race conditions are causing the 2nd instance query return the updated `DeploymentLock`?

Maybe add some logging or `println` debugging to print the version value right before the update.  If it does show that the versions are the same then can you edit your post to show how you are making the update call?

Comment: Do you have some documentation about JPA/Hibernate Lock in cluster environment?